# Text-decoration: underline; not working on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, underline

Here's my problem: I have underlined certain elements in my navbar as well as my headers H2 and H1. It works as I intended in the desktop version as well as in the mobile version of the chrome developer tools, but when I use a real mobile device, none of the underlines are showing (neither on chrome nor edge).

Could someone help me with this ?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.articlechild h2 {
  margin: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: wavy #25fde9 underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="articlecontainer">
  <div class="articlechild">
    <h1>Article Title</h1>
    <h2>Introduction</h2>
```

Comment: Any specific mobile browser?

Comment: Maybe is a cache problem, try to delete cache or add a version to your css file

Comment: I've tried both safari and chrome on my mobile device. None of them is working. I've also tried deleting the cache and it did not work ...

Comment: Have you checked https://caniuse.com/text-decoration already?

Comment: All the modern browsers support text-decoration: underline. However it seems the 'wavy' part is something too new.
Have you tried to change the property order text-decoration: underline wavy blue. And to put -webkit for Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same problem but without the "wavy" part. Just old fashioned "text-decoration:underline;"

worked perfect on desktop. not at all on mobile.

Turned out to be a caching issue for me.

I had recently created a new .underline{} class in my site.css file and called it with  but the new css file was apparently not updating on my mobile device. I don't know how to force a full reload on my mobile (Android Chrome)...? so I just viewed the page incognito and it retrieved a fresh copy of the site.css
It's still not showing correctly in normal browsing mode but I assume the css file will update itself eventually.